# TikZ: centring a picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

My code fails to align the drawing so that the line SR (centre of the graph excerpt) is in the middle of the page. It is noticeable that the drawing is shifted to the left when compared to the text above, and the caption and pagination below the drawing.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

...some text here...

\begin{align*}
    \sec{\varphi}=\frac{|OS|}{|OR|}=\frac{|OS|}{1}=|OS|
& & \cot{\varphi}=\frac{|OU|}{|OT|}=\frac{|OU|}{1}=|OU|
\end{align*}

{\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]

    \def\costhirty{0.8660256}
    \def\secthirty{1.1547}
    \def\sinfifteen{-0.258819}
    \def\cosfifteen{0.9659258}

    \draw[color=gray,dotted,step=1cm] (-0.25,-0.25) grid (2.25,1.25);   

    \draw (\cosfifteen,\sinfifteen) arc (-15:105:1cm);

    \draw[color=gray,dotted] (0,0) -- (30:2.5cm);
    \draw[color=gray,dotted] (30:1cm) -- +(-90:0.75cm);
    \draw[color=gray,dotted] (30:1cm) -- +(90:0.75cm);

    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (P) at (\costhirty, 0);
    \coordinate (Q) at (30:1cm);
    \coordinate (R) at (1, 0);
    \coordinate (S) at (30:\secthirty);
    \coordinate (T) at (0, 1);
    \coordinate (U) at (30:2);

    \draw[thick] (O)--(90:1.25);
    \draw[thick] (O)--(0:2.25);

    \draw[thick] (Q)--(P);
    \draw[thick] (O)--(U)--(T);
    \draw[thick] (R)--(S);

    \tkzLabelPoints[below left](O)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below left](P)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left = 5pt of Q](Q)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below right](R)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below right](S)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above left](T)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](U)

    \tkzMarkAngle[fill = gray, size=0.3cm, opacity = .3](P,O,Q)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.2](P,O,Q){$\varphi$}

    \tkzMarkAngle[fill = gray, size=0.3cm, opacity = .3](T,U,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos = -0.2](O,U,T){$\varphi$}

\end{tikzpicture}

\textit{\scriptsize{Figure 2}}

}

\end{document}
```

The code above results in in the following preview. (The double red line has been added subsequently.)

[image: Drawing]

How can I have the line SR centred to be aligned with the rest of the content that goes through the double red line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but the `tkz-euclide` angle-marking macros must use some internal control points that go outside the bounding box of the graphic.

The solution is to encase them inside a `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

...some text here...

\begin{align*}
    \sec{\varphi}=\frac{|OS|}{|OR|}=\frac{|OS|}{1}=|OS|
& & \cot{\varphi}=\frac{|OU|}{|OT|}=\frac{|OU|}{1}=|OU|
\end{align*}

{\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]

    \def\costhirty{0.8660256}
    \def\secthirty{1.1547}
    \def\sinfifteen{-0.258819}
    \def\cosfifteen{0.9659258}

    \draw[color=gray,dotted,step=1cm] (-0.25,-0.25) grid (2.25,1.25);   

    \draw (\cosfifteen,\sinfifteen) arc (-15:105:1cm);

    \draw[color=gray,dotted] (0,0) -- (30:2.5cm);
    \draw[color=gray,dotted] (30:1cm) -- +(-90:0.75cm);
    \draw[color=gray,dotted] (30:1cm) -- +(90:0.75cm);

    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (P) at (\costhirty, 0);
    \coordinate (Q) at (30:1cm);
    \coordinate (R) at (1, 0);
    \coordinate (S) at (30:\secthirty);
    \coordinate (T) at (0, 1);
    \coordinate (U) at (30:2);

    \draw[thick] (O)--(90:1.25);
    \draw[thick] (O)--(0:2.25);

    \draw[thick] (Q)--(P);
    \draw[thick] (O)--(U)--(T);
    \draw[thick] (R)--(S);

    \tkzLabelPoints[below left](O)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below left](P)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left = 5pt of Q](Q)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below right](R)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below right](S)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above left](T)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](U)
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \tkzMarkAngle[fill = gray, size=0.3cm, opacity = .3](P,O,Q)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.2](P,O,Q){$\varphi$}
        \tkzMarkAngle[fill = gray, size=0.3cm, opacity = .3](T,U,O)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos = -0.2](O,U,T){$\varphi$}
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}

\textit{\scriptsize{Figure 2}}

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Minifying the example a bit shows the problem more clearly with some "instrumentation" for testing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

...some text here... \hrulefill

\begin{align*}
    \sec{\varphi}=\frac{|OS|}{|OR|}=\frac{|OS|}{1}=|OS|
& & \cot{\varphi}=\frac{|OU|}{|OT|}=\frac{|OU|}{1}=|OU|
\end{align*}

{\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (P) at ({cos(30)}, 0);
    \coordinate (Q) at (30:1cm);
    \coordinate (R) at (1, 0);
    \coordinate (S) at (30:{sec(30)});
    \coordinate (T) at (0, 1);
    \coordinate (U) at (30:2);

    \draw[thick] (Q)--(P);
    \draw[thick] (O)--(U)--(T);
    \draw[thick] (R)--(S);

    \node[red] at (current bounding box.south) {$\vert$};
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \tkzMarkAngle[fill = gray, size=0.3cm, opacity = .3](P,O,Q)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.2](P,O,Q){$\varphi$}
        \tkzMarkAngle[fill = gray, size=0.3cm, opacity = .3](T,U,O)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos = -0.2](O,U,T){$\varphi$}
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \node[blue] at (current bounding box.south) {$\vert$};
\end{tikzpicture}

$\vert$

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice how, with the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment, all three `\vert`s are aligned. Commenting out this environment will show the misalignment introduced to the bounding box by the angle-marking macros.